# Setting up a drupal site on local apache2 server on linux mint

Tags: apache, heroku, drupal, drupal-7

I have been given a drupal website to work on and I have pretty much no experience with drupal of apache. I am trying to set up the drupal site on my local machine so I can edit it then eventually push the changes back up to github. The problem is I can't seem to make apache work with it. I am running linux mint and I have made a new .conf file in /etc/apache2/site-available and added this to the top:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Then added my document root path correctly then added my environment variables. I then restart apache and go to local host. I am getting the right icon on my tab so I know at least some of the things are working but it is just a blank page. If I navigate to index.php it is still blank. If i navigate directly to a html page it gives me the html but none of the css is working. If anyone has any advice or good links for tutorials that could help I would be very thankful.
Thank you.

Comment: Just try to give 777 permission to files folder. I think the issue is with the css aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the host database wasn't working with my machine so I downloaded it locally and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 (the core) is supporting PHP 7, but a lot of modules are not, so generally it's not a good idea to run Drupal 7 site on PHP 7. Better switch to PHP 5.x if that's an option.

For start create some small php file containint only phpinfo() function call and open it to see is Apache and then PHP running well or not. If it doesn't then it's not Drupal issue, but web server issue.

If it does then see where error log is, enable logging if it's disabled, check the log to see what happens...